# order agenda so all-day and multi-day duration items appear on top

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, sorting

My problem is with two of my main use-cases for time-stamped items (essentially events). Consider these two org-mode items:

```
 * Clojure Dojo at uSwitch <2016-11-14 Mon 19:00>
 * Trip to Jamaica <2016-12-14 Wed>-<2017-01-02 Mon>
```

For the first item, simple date+time stamped events appear in the agenda on the top in the time-scale view of the day.

I use multi-day duration events for the purpose to remind me major contexts (like being abroad, on holiday, etc.), based on which I might have to adjust my priorities for those days.

My question is, how can I sort the agenda items, so that all-day events (including multi-day duration) are on top of the agenda?

Whether the all-day/multi-day items should appear above the daily time-scale, or below, is not important. Actually, I would look forward to look at both if possible.

I was told to look into the `org-agenda-sorting-strategy` option, and write a user defined function for it. I would like to ask for an example `elisp` code to achieves the above.

Might worth noting that I am mostly using day view agenda. Not sure how such changes could affect the yearly, monthly, or other agenda views...